# How to send emails to specific people (subscribers) of a scheduled job's status in Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a scheduled job running in Gitlab that runs a bunch of tests every night. Upon job failure I need to notify specific people. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [Project integrations](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/)

You can find the available integrations under your project’s Settings ➔ Integrations page. You need to have at least maintainer permission on the project.

List of integrations — https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/integrations/overview.html#integrations-listing

What you are asking is `Pipelines emails` ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veTEZ.png))

Comment: I am not sure if this does exactly what I want. Branches to be notified has very limited options and it seems one cannot subscribe to specific pipelines.